# predicting Missing Words in a sentence with additional information

Tags: nlp

I have a sentence below:

```
it claimed that some 250,000 people __ the rally.
```

I want to predict the missing word with Bert. And I know some additional information,like the topic of this sentence. what should I do to predict it using additional information? Is there any paper for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a paper about this problem. But I assume you can just attach your additional information to your input sentence after the `[SEP]` token (as if it was the second sentence), and it will improve the prediction quality.

If you have a dataset labeled with additional information that is large enough, you can fine-tune a BERT using the setup described above, and it could improve the quality even further.